# What is the cost of changing the search path in postgres in a schema-per tenant model

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I am working on a multi-tenant storage gateway.

Each tenant has his own schema -- the schema for each tenant is a meta-schema so each tenant schema is identical. The DB interactions only occur through a stored procedure API. The stored procedure layer is on the public schema. The stored procedures rely on the search_path being set to `<TENANT_SCHEMA>;public`.

The application layer prepares statements against the stored procedures in the public schema.

I have a stored procedure for switching the tenant that looks as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION domains_switch(domain DOMAIN_NAME) RETURNS VOID AS $$ BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM public.domains WHERE domain_name = domain) THEN
    EXECUTE format('set search_path=%s,public;', domain);
  ELSE
    RAISE 'domain "%" does not exist',domain USING ERRCODE = 'AX001';
  END IF;
  RETURN; END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`plpgsql` stored procedures manage plans themselves which means I only need to prepare the api statements once per backend in the gateway. I suspect the stored procedure's internal cached plans are invalidated when I switch the schema.

I am planning to add a layer to the gateway's connection pool management to minimise search_path switches. Is my intuition correct? Is this the right thing to do?

Comment: What is a `typeless graph storage/incremental event processing engine`? And how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: I have edited the question -- I thought it would be relevant to scope the question. The gateway is sending streams of events to the database, some are multi-event transactions but most are self contained. switching the search path will happen very often.

Comment: Your Postgres version is essential to the question. (It almost always is.)

Comment: Postgres 9.6.2 -- fresh project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your intuition is correct. Changing the `search_path` causes Postgres to start from scratch with prepared statements. [The manual on `PREPARE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-prepare.html)

> Also, if the value of `search_path` changes from one use to the next,
>   the statement will be re-parsed using the new `search_path`. (This
>   latter behavior is new as of PostgreSQL 9.3.)

And SQL statements inside PL/pgSQL functions are treated like prepared statements.

Especially while working with connection poolers (same connection stays open), it will help performance if you keep switching the `search_path` to a minimum.

The extra cost is not too high for simple statements, but it may be a noticeable effect for more complex queries.